# Put an applet in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, xhtml, applet

I have made an applet in eclipse, and I can run it succesfully with right click on the java file and run as -> Java Applet

But I want to add that applet into a xhtml file, so added the applet tag in the index.xhtml file but when I deploy the index.xhtml in the browser I just get an error saying that the MyApplet.class cannot be found

```
<applet code="com.project.helper.MyApplet.class" width="500" height="500">
```

I have the files organized in this way:

[Image with the body of the files](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2qulsa4rpe4gswf/Files.JPG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must define the archive attribute of the applet xhtml line, which is the location of your applet's jar file from which the class attribute should be loaded.

```
<applet code="com.project.helper.MyApplet.class" archive="MyApplet.jar" width="500" height="500">
```

Comment: thank you!
I can add the applet in this way, but even this way my applet doesn't work as it is supposed to.
The applet works with a USB device, and when I right click on the java file and run it as an applet it works good, but adding to the xhtml file it doesn't work, it just keeps blank and does nothing
The applet is supposed to work with a USB device that get a digital signature, here is the applet code:
http://pastebin.com/GQbq7vX9